# NDB -- How to know if an entity has been contained under a root Key

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to add player's data into NDB. However before I add them, I have to check whether the data exists in datastore or not. I can't find the obvious answer in official docs. Can anyone give me a simple code and explanation about this problem? Here is part of my code.

```
self.player = Player(parent=ndb.Key("Players", "PlayersKeys"), name = self.request.get("Name"), playerid = self.request.get("ID"))
self.player.put()
```

Update-------------------

By using query, if it contains the data, then qry.get() would not be None.

**Here is my solution:**

```
qry = Player.query(Player.userid == self.request.get("ID"))
if qry.get() == None:
    # put the data to datastore
    self.player = Player(parent=ndb.Key("Players", "PlayersKeys"), name = self.request.get("Name"), userid = playerid)
    self.player.put()
else:
     # Do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the id of the entity, which is playerid in your case, and the key of the parent.

Therefore

```
myPlayer = Player.get_by_id(int(playerid),parent=parentKey)
if myPlayer:
    #The player already exists... do something
    pass
else:
    #The player does not exist (yet) you can create it
    pass
```

**UPDATE**

try

```
   playerCount= Player.query(Player.userid ==self.request.get("ID")).count(keys_only=True)
   if PlayerCount>0:
       #the player already exists
       pass
   else: 
       #the player does not exist
       pass
```

This shouldn't increase the number of read operations

Comment: This count as a read operation. If you are only interested to know whether the player exists or not, and you don't need to know any other property of the existing player, you may just  make a query with the ancestor and the id followed by count(keys_only=True) which means that the datastore will only count the existing keys returned by the query. This shouldn't increase the read operations.

Comment: I tried your code above, however, my playid is too long which can't convert to integer. When using string as id, the get_by_id method always returns none. Is there any other way to get the entity with a specific string identifier ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found it is also feasible to use query to know whether it contains or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [Player.get_or_insert](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert)

```
player_key = Player.query(Player.userid == self.request.get("ID")).get(keys_only=True)
player = Player.get_or_insert(player_key, **data)
```